# Задача: Эстафета. У меня вот такой код, но на сайте решение проходит не полностью, можете пожалуйста посмотреть мой код и сказать ошибку

Tags: python

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVlGE.png]

```
    l = input().split()
    n = 0
    m = 1
    a = l[-1]
    a = int(a)
    f = 0
    for i in range(a-1):
        z = l[n]
        r = l[m]
        z = int(z)
        r = int(r)
        if r <= z:
            f = f + (z-r)
        else:
            f = f + (r-z)
        n += 1
        m += 1
    print(f)
```

Comment: спасибо, что убрали картинку

Comment: складываете всё в список lst и `print(sum(abs(a-b) for a,b in zip(lst[:-1], lst[1:])))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная ошибка - большая избыточность кода. Отлаживать вам сложно. Python же требует простоты.
Несколько комментариев даны по тексту ниже. Изучите отличия от вашего кода, поймите, зачем вы вводили избыточность. Проверьте код ниже.
(И в приниципе, 4 строки в цикле можно записать в одну тернарным оператором, но сложнее будет понимать).

```
# PEP-8 не рекомендует односимвольный 'l', заменим на 'line'
# Стандартный ввод чисел в список с преобразованием типа каждого
line = list(map(int, input().split()))
f = 0
# Информации в списке достаточно для вычислений
for i in range(len(line)-1):
    if line[i+1] > line[i]:
        f += line[i+1] - line[i]
    elif line[i+1] < line[i]:
        f += line[i] - line[i+1]
print(f)
```

Comment: спасибо, галочку поставил

Comment: кстати, если вы уже проходили, что такое модуль числа, то все 4 строки в цикле можно заменить на одну: `f += abs(line[i+1] - line[i])`

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю свои 5 копеек:

```py
from itertools import starmap
points = [8, 5, 15, 8, 5]
print(
  sum(
    # суммируем < ------------------------------------------
                                                          # ^
    starmap(                                              # |
      # Вычисляем разницу этих элементов <------------------
      # и возвращаем ее абсолютное значение применяя лямбду ^
      # к получившейся последовательности кортежей          |
      lambda x, y: abs(y - x),                            # |
      # создаем последовательность кортежей                 |
      # из пар следующих друг за другом элементов ----------
      zip(
        points[:-1], 
        points[1:]
      )
    )
  )
)
```

---

> Ну или вот так (для любителей однострочников)
> `print(sum(starmap(lambda x, y: abs(y - x), zip(points[:-1], points[1:]))))`

Comment: большое спасибо